# android-wants to put Button above listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using linear layout inside that one button and one list view..
list-view is adding its item dynamically at the run-time..
so at that time button goes behind list-view and not visible and list-view fit in whole layout.

**I want to put Button above the List view and it must also stay after loading list-view**

Thanks in Advance

my .xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_searchNewDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Search New Devices"
      />   

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_add_newDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

here it is search new device button.

click on that button device search for Bluetooth and add into listview
[image]

so this is thing happen in my application..

Answer (score 1):

I think even this works.Give a try

edited...

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_searchNewDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"

        android:text="Search New Devices"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_add_newDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_searchNewDevices" 
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the activity is as follows .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Button mBTNSearch;
    private static ListView mLV_list;
    ArrayList<String> devicesList;
    SparseBooleanArray checked;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mBTNSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_searchNewDevices);
        devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        mLV_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_add_newDevices);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devicesList);
        mBTNSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
      mLV_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        adapter.add("new Device");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

The output capture is as below

[image]

Comment: Give other Solution..it gives same output as mine

Comment: post how you are adding the items if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:layout_weight="1"` in the listview's height to that you make sure your button will always be seen in the screen.

You should try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_searchNewDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Search New Devices"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_add_newDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can use ListView's [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) method. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-listactivity-with-a-header-or-footer/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your Layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It give same output as mine..Give other Solution

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your listview inside a scrollview.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_searchNewDevices"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Search New Devices"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dip"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_add_newDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

It might work. I haven't tested, so not sure.